# MySQL BEFORE INSERT Trigger Select Into Multiple Variables?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger in MySQL and I need to set the values of several variables.  The values I need to put into these variables are from a row in an existing table (not worried about multiple rows, there will only be one):

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER ins_move_to_hist BEFORE INSERT ON EndOfDay
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DECLARE _RowsMatching int;
 DECLARE _EodId  int(10) unsigned;
  DECLARE _Open  decimal(6,4);
  DECLARE _High  decimal(6,4);
  DECLARE _Low   decimal(6,4);
  DECLARE _Close  decimal(6,4);
  DECLARE _Volume  int(10) unsigned;
  DECLARE _mtime  datetime;

 SELECT _RowsMatching = Count(*), 
  EodId as _EodId, 
  Open as _Open,
  High as _High,
  Low as _Low,
  Close as _Close,
  Volume as _Volume,
  mtime as _mtime
 from EndOfDay 
 where DateId = NEW.DateId
  and TickerId = NEW.TickerId;
```

However, Triggers don't allow for Selecting results (which I don't need).  So, when I run the create script it gives me this error:

> Not allowed to return a result set
>   from a trigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you simply need to change your as statements to into statements.

UPDATE:
As Bill corrected me below, the INTO statement is formatted more like the insert statement, ie; column list INTO value list.

```
SELECT Count(*), EodId, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, mtime 
INTO _RowsMatching, _EodId, _Open, _High, _Low, _Close, _Volume, _mtime
...
```

Thanks, Bill. ;)

Comment: +1 You're on the right track, but your syntax needs some work.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into-statement.html

Comment: Oh good lord, that's right! ^_^

I guess I really need to verify these kinds of things instead of attempting to rely on my less than dependable powers of recollection. heheh. Thanks, Bill.