# MySQL How to inside a Trigger, Select Multiple rows and then insert them

Tags: mysql, logging, select, triggers, insert

I am creating a "log" system and for this, trigger would be the best way to go I think. The thing is I have a header table (table1) and a line item table (table2). I created 2 new tables (table1log) and (table2log) they are copies of the non-log table. I want that when I update a row in the header table (table1), it will store the current row values in the log table (table1log), but I also want to store every row with the same header_id from (table2) into (table2log). So I created a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, the part to save the updated row in (table1) is working, but when it comes to saving (table2) rows, it don't work. It says I can't return a result set from trigger nor I can't create a view.

I tried to use a plain select and insert, I was expecting it to work, but It returned this
`Error 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger SQL Statement`

I also tried to create a view inside the trigger and then simply get my data from the view, but it returned this
`Error 1422: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger SQL Statement`

I've tried everything that is talked in these subjects, but none seems to be exactly what I want.

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317937/triggers-for-multiple-rows-at-once
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html
- [mysql trigger after update select multiple rows with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331743/mysql-trigger-after-update-select-multiple-rows-with-multiple-columns)
- https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,656502,656502
- [How to insert multiple records from a trigger in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104742/how-to-insert-multiple-records-from-a-trigger-in-mysql)
- [Database trigger select multiple rows and insert into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443746/database-trigger-select-multiple-rows-and-insert-into-table)
- [MySQL BEFORE INSERT Trigger Select Into Multiple Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750458/mysql-before-insert-trigger-select-into-multiple-variables)

> ```
> CREATE DEFINER='root'@'%' TRIGGER 'dev'.'table1_BEFORE_UPDATE' BEFORE UPDATE ON "table1" FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     INSERT INTO dev.table1log
>       (NumHeader, Name)
>       VALUES (OLD.NumHeader, OLD.Name);
>     
>     SELECT * INTO @table2v FROM dev.table2 WHERE NumHeader = OLD.NumHeader;
>     
>     INSERT INTO dev.table2log
>       (NumHeader, Name)
>       VALUES (@table2v.NumHeader, @table2v.Name);
> END
> ```

I am looking to do something like this, can anyone enlighten me on how I should do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL a variable only for a single scalar, not a result set.

But you don't need any variables in your case, because you can use [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'%' TRIGGER dev.table1_BEFORE_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dev.table1log
      (NumHeader, Name)
      VALUES (OLD.NumHeader, OLD.Name);
    
    INSERT INTO dev.table2log
      (NumHeader, Name)
      SELECT NumHeader, Name
      FROM dev.table2
      WHERE NumHeader = OLD.NumHeader;
END
```

I also edited to change this to an AFTER trigger, because you want it to run after the UPDATE that spawned the trigger is successful. If you do the inserts in a BEFORE trigger, but the UPDATE fails, then it would have to roll back more changes.

I also fixed the incorrect use of quote marks.